# Numbered list in UITextView with editing

Tags: list, numbers, uitextview

If there any framework to use numbered lists in a `UITextView`? Something like Evernote does?

Comment: Do you want only this feature or whole set or text editing options from Evernote? And second question - do you want to add new list item dynamically or just show list with needed formatting?

Comment: First question it doesn't matter, I just need some kind of algorithm, and for second dynamically and static